# Memory issue with using a C pointer object (CGImageRef) defined outside in a GCD dispatch queue block

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, pointers, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I'm reading an image from disk into a UIImage, and using its CGImage in another worker queue block for media processing.

Now I'm getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS if I define a CGImageRef in the main queue, and use the CGImageRef in the worker queue. Like this:

```
UIImage *uiimage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[aPhoto completeLargeThumbFilePath]];

CGImageRef cgImage = uiimage.CGImage;

dispatch_queue_t    dispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("mediaInputQueue", NULL);
[writerInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:dispatchQueue usingBlock:^{

    // ... unrelated stuff
    CVPixelBufferRef buffer = (CVPixelBufferRef)[self pixelBufferFromCGImage:cgImage size:size];
    // ... unrelated stuff
}];
```

If I use uiimage.CGImage directly in the worker queue, then I don't get the exception. I think this is related to the ARC memory management. UIImage is an objective-c object, and CGImageRef is a pointer to an C struct. The UIImage is released before I can use its CGImage in the first case.

My question is how can I directly use a C pointer defined in main queue in another dispatch queue?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756295/uiimage-from-cgimageref ?

Comment: It's the same cause in two different scenarios. Thanks, the discussion in that thread is very informative!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you have this problem, and the reason that `CGImageRetain()` fixes it, is because the `CGImage` is not retained by the block. This is because `CGImageRef` is not an Objective-C object pointer type. Blocks only automatically retain captured variables when they are Objective-C object pointer types.

So an alternate solution is to simply let the block capture an "object pointer type" version of it (all Core Foundation objects can be treated as Cocoa Objective-C objects, and vice versa):

```
UIImage *uiimage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[aPhoto completeLargeThumbFilePath]];

CGImageRef cgImage = uiimage.CGImage;

id cgImageAsObject = (__bridge id)cgImage;

dispatch_queue_t    dispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("mediaInputQueue", NULL);
[writerInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:dispatchQueue usingBlock:^{

    // ... unrelated stuff
    CGImageRef cgImageAgain = (__bridge CGImageRef)cgImageAsObject;
    CVPixelBufferRef buffer = (CVPixelBufferRef)[self pixelBufferFromCGImage:cgImageAgain size:size];
    // ... unrelated stuff
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I think this is more general for things with out retain methods like CGImageRetain().

Comment: @XiaochaoYang: Yeah. Retaining outside the block and releasing inside the block is not good memory management practice, because if the block is not run, then you have a leak; and if the block is run more than once, you have an over-release.

Comment: Once a block is dispatched, it *will always be run*.  GCD does not have a cancellation API.  Thus, retaining outside of the queue and releasing inside the block is safe, it is a carry over of the design pattern of *retain on thread A, release on thread B*.  However, I would also generally prefer @newacct's pattern because it takes the onus of thinking this through away from the developer.  I would actually prefer moving the `CGImageRef cgImage = uiimage.CGImage;` into the block and ditching the two casts entirely;  they aren't necessary.

Comment: @bbum: Right, but that assumes that the `requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:usingBlock:` method does what you expect. Using `uiimage.CGImage` works in this case because there's an "associated" Objective-C object, the UIImage object, in this case. However, 1) It may be that using the UIImage object uses more resources than the CGImage object (I'm not sure if that's true, but it might be for other objects) so you may not want to keep it around; or 2) In general you might not have such an associated Objective-C object for a given Core Foundation object.

Comment: Alternatively, using the interior pointer assumes that the object will survive the destruction of the containing object.   Damned if you do, damned if you don't.

Comment: @bbum: the *object* will definitely survive (it's retained by the block); the object's contents might possibly be cleared

Comment: @newacct If I have a `UIImage` and I call `CGImage`, whether I do so within the block our outside the block is *completely irrelevant*.    Keeping the `UIImage` around is far, far, more defensive of a coding practice than using the interior pointer, in general.   Now, in the case of the CGImage that it can be retained preserves it.   But consider `NSData`'s `-bytes` method.  The only way to preserve that across the queue boundary is by hard retaining the `data` object.   Overall, I prefer the solution that I outlined in my answer *exactly because it is less code, less casts, and less complex!*

Answer (score 2):

The `uiimage` is autoreleased.   Thus, most likely, the `cgImage` is being deallocated when the `UIImage` is autoreleased.

You could try retaining the `cgImage` and then releasing it in the block.   Or you could use the `uiimage` in the block (add `[uiimage self];` to the end of the block -- looks goofy, but works).

The underlying issue is what is called the *interior pointer problem*.   You are grabbing a pointer to something inside an object, but not maintaining a strong reference to the object.  When the object goes away, whatever the *interior pointer* points to is reaped and you are left with a dangling pointer.

I'd go with this:

```
UIImage *uiimage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[aPhoto completeLargeThumbFilePath]];

dispatch_queue_t    dispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("mediaInputQueue", NULL);
[writerInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:dispatchQueue usingBlock:^{
    CGImageRef cgImage = uiimage.CGImage;

    // ... unrelated stuff
    CVPixelBufferRef buffer = (CVPixelBufferRef)[self pixelBufferFromCGImage:cgImage size:size];
    // ... unrelated stuff
}];
```

Comment: Thanks, so CGImageRetain() and CGImageRelease() are the solution!